# Need H2 to be only as wide as the text, but also text-align:center

Tags: html, css

I have two columns with H2 tags at the top of each column. The text in the `H2` tags is short. The tags have a blue background. This is part of the problem, because as normal inline elements, the blue background will span the width of the div columns. Changing the `H2` to `display:inline-block` will fix this, but that introduces another problem, that `text-align:center` no longer works, and the `H2` tags will then align left.

How do I get an H2 element to both only be as wide as the text **and** align center?

```
<div style="width:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
<h2 style="display:inline-block;background-color:#558ED5;color:#FFF;text-align:center;font-size:1.1em;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">WE OFFER 2 CLEANING OPTIONS:</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Without showing more of the HTML, ideally an example of both 'columns,' both headings, and the CSS that constrains the width of those columns there's no way to reliably answer this question. Please: show enough ("[MCVE]") code to allow us to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add text-align:center; to main div. like this:

```
<div style="width:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; text-align:center">
    <h2 style="display:inline-block;background-color:#558ED5;color:#FFF;text-align:center;font-size:1.1em;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">WE OFFER 2 CLEANING OPTIONS:</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: BINGO!, it works. Will be checked as right answer in 9 minutes, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the container div to text-align:center which will make h2 that has display:inline-block to be centered

```html
<div style="width:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center">
<h2 style="display:inline-block;background-color:#558ED5;color:#FFF;text-align:center;font-size:1.1em;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">WE OFFER 2 CLEANING OPTIONS:</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks great! Thanks.